# Is there any other way to ensure that pdf file will not be printed under Acrobat?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I am aware that password security for Acrobat X can be easily compromised. Is there any other way to ensure that pdf file will not be printed? Is there any way to limit the view of pdf files with specified person (identified with emails)?